# What does "lest anything think" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/vi/dictionary/english/lest?q=lest+

And lest anything think Nike is pulling back from physical retail even as its digital business explodes, the company said it's full steam ahead with the new stores it was already planning to open, including two New York stores in the next two weeks, the CEO said.

Source: https://fortune.com/2020/09/23/nike-q1-ecommerce-results-covid-19/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make sense. Things don't think. It should say "Lest anyone think...".

It may be an editing error; the sentence may have started as "Lest anything make people think...", and then may have been edited incorrectly.